# Expected identifier or '(' issue when adding WKWebview in Xcode objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am receiving the error message and cannot figure out why. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnzLT.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The image is under enter image description here sorry

Comment: You appear to have pasted Swift code into Objective-C. That's not going to work!

Comment: Thank you the code from Apple is producing errors. I'll see how to setup. Thank you